# Emacs falsely recommends removal of explicitly installed packages - Why?

Tags: package, list-packages

I am encountering a peculiar issue with Emacs's package management system where it is falsely recommending the removal of packages that I have explicitly installed via `package-install`. One such example is the `markdown-mode` package.

I have installed the affected packages explicitly using `M-x package-install`, so they are not dependencies.

I am using Emacs's built-in `package.el` for package management.

This behaviour is consistent and affects packages that I want to keep.

The recommendation for removal occurs when I go to the list of packages (`M-x list-packages`) and press capital "U" to update packages. Emacs then prompts me to update the packages and recommends certain packages for removal, even though I want to keep them.

I have checked the usual scenarios such as package dependencies and made sure I am using the correct installation method. I am unable to identify why this is happening.

This thread provides a workaround but does not explain why the package is excluded or indicate that it is a problem that will be rectified:

[How does package-autoremove decide which packages to remove?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18253/how-does-package-autoremove-decide-which-packages-to-remove)

Why is Emacs recommending the removal of these explicitly installed packages, and is this behaviour which I have observed for a long time going to be fixed?

Emacs Version: 30

Any insights or guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe I have seen that behavior but I have not stopped to investigate further. A bug report (`M-x report-emacs-bug`) is probably a good idea, if only to get an explanation of why this happens.

Comment: Maybe `M-x report-emacs-bug`?

Comment: Did  you check the value of the `package-selected-packages` variable as suggested in the other question? Including the value in your own question will clarify the matter.

Comment: I did check the value. The packages listed do not correspond to those in my `.emacs.d` folder under `elpa`. Packages are listed that have been uninstalled, and at least one installed package is not listed there, the same package `package-autoremove` wishes to remove.

Comment: Then you already have the answer: add the package that you don’t want it to autoremove to the list.

Comment: Yes, that is the soution, but what is the problem?